# How to get full path location of file in HTML

Tags: python, html

I am trying to return file path on click of Submit button in HTML. File path has to be sent to python variable. Requirement is user can select file and if this file location is different than pre-configured file location then new file location should be updated in python. But only file name is being returned.

```
<label for="excel">Choose file location: </label>
<input type="file" id="excel" name="excel" accept=".xlsx, .xlx, .doc, .pdf">
```

example.py

```
file = request.form.get("excel")
if 'Update File Location' in action:
    if file:
       c.update_file_location(file)
```

As of now, only selected file name is returned in 'file'. But I want to get file path also along with filename.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your python code as well.

Comment: The HTML FILE input element will not reveal details of the local filesystem. To do so would be a massive security issue so you are limited to the filename, type and size

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius What if files are in Network or shared folder?

Comment: potentially even more of an issue ( revealing details of network or other machines ) - but would still be classified as "Filesystem"